# Git squash specific commits

Tags: git, github, squash

Im using the rebase tool to squash  the last 3 commits
and by **mistake** I did 
with git rebase -i HEAD~4 
this command open the VI interactive tool like following

```
d 041a84a Fix docs buil(#4)
p 8896b6d handle users
s 8759e73 add new users
s b485efd add phones
```

the 041a84a is not related and I mark it as `d` but **not sure** if it will remove it from the this branch only **or** when I submit it to the master
it still r**emove it from the master** which I **DONT** want, I just want to remove it from my branch …
if I can exit from the VI tool and change it to  `git rebase -i HEAD~3` ??

Comment: What does "submit it to the master" mean? If your current branch is not master, your master won't be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem your were in state such as this :

```
master :     --A--B 
branch :          \--C--C'--C"
```

Where:
**B** is 041a84a ;
**C** is 8896b6d ;
**C'** and **C"** must be squashed.

Now, if you apply

```
d B  Fix docs buil(#4)
p C  handle users
s C' add new users
s C" add phones
```

This should result in branches looking like :

```
master :    --A--B 
branch :       \--C*
```

This means that master will **not** be changed and only the history of the branch you are currently rebasing will be changed.

Finally, to answer *"if I can exit from the VI tool and change it to git rebase -i HEAD~3"*.
You can exit VI without writing anything with *q!* and then your are free to do `git rebase -i HEAD~3`

Comment: typo: with q! instead of w!